# Using MonoDroid, how can I open a dialog when an EditText field gains focus?

Tags: dialog, focus, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I made the EditText clickable but you have to "double-click" to bring the dialog box up, which isn't really desired behaviour. How can I bring the dialog box up when the EditText is clicked / gains focus?

Bonus points for including a way to stop the keyboard popping up :)

```cs
        _createProfileDobEdtTxt.Clickable = true;

        _createProfileDobEdtTxt.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ShowDialog(DATE_OF_BIRTH_DIALOG);
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it - use the .Touch event handler:

```cs
  _createProfileDobEdtTxt.Touch += (sender, e) =>
     {
        ShowDialog(DATE_OF_BIRTH_DIALOG);
     };
```